# Errors after upgrading to Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

My function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: NSDictionary)
```

Shows this error:

> Objective-C method 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:' provided by method 'application(:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

I saw on another post that it fixes by just "rewriting" the methods name. What does it mean? Change the name? Delete it and write it again?

Comment: If you're going to ask about advice given elsewhere, it'd probably be a good idea to mention the source of the advice so that users who'd understand it could see the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 1.2 further moves away from its Objective-C foundations by remapping some class methods from the `NSDictionary` type to the native Swift `[NSObject: AnyObject]` type.

Change your method header to this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

You can fix other errors of this sort by using the Swift conversion tool, which can be found in the Edit menu under "Convert" (`Edit -> Convert -> To Latest Swift Syntax...`).

I assume what is meant by "rewriting" the method header in your other source is deleting the line and typing `application(`, then selecting the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` option from the popup menu and allowing autocomplete to do the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `NSDictionary` with `[NSObject : AnyObject]`.